# What is the best way to show 7 small questions in a single screen?

Tags: forms, questionnaire

I'm working on a questionnaire which got 7 different questions with 2 types of an answer for each one, regular workdays and weekend.
Here's the screen:
[image: Meal Questionnaire]

My question is how do I design the screen more usable, or how do I reduce the sense of overwhelming on this page without breaking the screen into multiple screens whith one question each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you're asking your user too many questions, perhaps consider a way of getting the same info in fewer questions. I think if you ask your user for times, you can calculate where they are and how many times they eat implicitly. I would also have a "tabbed view" for "week day" and "weekend" (not everyone goes to work, but they all have weekdays and weekends)

```
(Weekdays tab) (Weekends tab)

Wake at 07:00

[x] Leave home 08:00
[x] Return home 18:00

[x] Breakfast 09:00
[x] Lunch     13:00
[x] Dinner    20:00

Sleep at 23:00
```

Using the times you can know whether they eat (at work) or in the house. You can know how many meals they eat by how many are ticked. If meal size is important make it a choice between `big/small/no`  `breakfast/lunch/dinner` rather than a tick of `yes/no` `breakfast/lunch/dinner`

There may be the case that the person goes home for lunch even on a work day - if this is important I'd maybe have a "I lunch at home" tick under the "lunch" choice

Consider that a weekday routine and a weekend routine may not differ much; a button for the weekend that copies the habits from the weekday could approximately halve the count of details they have to enter, if they can copy then edit the few differences in that they undertake at a weekend.

If the reason for asking the work/home split is because you think they might have access to better cooking facilities at home, but in actual fact they have access to equivalent facilities at work, it may be worth letting them know that they should answer as if they stay at home all the time.

Comment: Thanks! I liked the workdays/weekend tabs separation and also the calculation behind the scenes based on the hours, the thing is that a lot of users, especially ones who're going to use such apps are eating more than 3 main meals a day, they can go 4 small ones like snacks and a one big one because they've got a serious workout in a specific day and for that the big/small/no is less of a solution but you helped me a lot and I will try to create something based on it. thanks again :-)

Comment: Ah, perhaps breakfast/lunch/dinner are just pre-created times that can be deleted if the user doesn't eat then and toggled for big/small. And of course users can add more mealtimes with custom names so if they snack 6 times a day they can setup their choices and references

Comment: Maybe but then my 1st option is the best, long but sure and usable, still need to think about it :-)

Comment: Your first option asks how many meals, before asking them to fill it - i'm proposing providing 3 standard meals and then having an add/delete button, so the count of meals is implied from how many are created rather than being a separate question that causes X number of blank meal entries to appear..